# Yammer External Network act as one

Tags: networking, external, office365, yammer

we want to have one landing page on Yammer enterprise for a group of companies already on yammer with different office365 domain/tenant but one owner

is there any sort of two way trust relationship

please help us to achieve that

Thanks,
Yousef

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an external Network to connect people from cross domains.

> **Networks > Browse External Network > Create Network**

NOTE: While External Networks can accommodate users with different email domains, access is generally invite-only.